# How do I select every instance of a class on a page, but not the first instance - regardless of parent?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I want to set every div with the class="wp-block-column" to 'display:none;' --> but not the first one.

I am having trouble :not selecting the first div with the class="wp-block-column"

BOTTOM LINE: I want to select all divs with the class="wp-block-column" throughout the page regardless of where they land or who their parent is --> but not the first instance. I want to select instances from the body, not a parent div.

`<div class="menu-column">` only appears inside `<div class="seventy-thirty-block">` but there could be 1 or 5 of these blocks, they are generated from a loop.

There could also be any number of blocks that are not `<div class="seventy-thirty-block">`before.

The css on this page works because :not(:nth-child(2) gets the second child of `<div class="singleBlogContent">`

But if I uncomment

```
<!--   

<div class="callout-full-block">
      </div>

  -->
```

then it no longer works because now it's :not(:nth-child(3)

Here is the JS Bin:
https://jsbin.com/xowefaj/edit?html,css,output

The output that I want in the JS Bin is:
content
menu
content
content

This is my html:

```
<div class="singleBlogContent">

  <div class="callout-full-block">
  </div> 

<!--   <div class="callout-full-block">
  </div>  -->
  
  <div class="seventy-thirty-block">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="seventy-thirty-columns">
        <div>
          <div>
            content
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wp-block-column">
          <div class="menu-column">
            menu
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <div class="seventy-thirty-block">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="seventy-thirty-columns">
        <div>
          <div>
            content
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wp-block-column">
          <div class="menu-column">
            menu
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>


  <div class="seventy-thirty-block">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="seventy-thirty-columns">
        <div>
          <div>
            content
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wp-block-column">
          <div class="menu-column">
            menu
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>

</div>
```

This is my css:

```
div.seventy-thirty-block:not(:nth-child(2)) .wp-block-column .menu-column {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign the first one a unique class then assign it `display: block;` after the initial ruleset for `display: none`. If you want a dynamic solution, you should use JavaScript. See **Figure I**

**Figure I**

```
document.querySelectorAll('.wp')[0].classList.add('.first');
```

```css
.wp {
  display: none;
}

.first {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class='wp first'>First</div>
  <div class='wp'>WP</div>
  <div class='wp'>WP</div>
  <div class='wp'>WP</div>
  <div class='wp'>WP</div>
  <div class='wp'>WP</div>
  <div class='wp'>WP</div>
  <div class='wp'>WP</div>
  <div class='wp'>WP</div>
  <div class='wp'>WP</div>
  <div class='wp'>WP</div>
  <div class='wp'>WP</div>
  <div class='wp'>WP</div>
  <div class='wp'>WP</div>
  <div class='wp'>WP</div>
  <div class='wp'>WP</div>
  <div class='wp'>WP</div>
</main>
```

Comment: What shall I do, code wise, to make that happen? Dynamically insert the class="first"

<div class="seventy-thirty-block"> blocks are generated in a loop, so difficult to place a class retro actively.

What's the solution? Gimme javascript, pleese.

Comment: It takes one line of JS, see update. Replace `.wp` with the appropriate class. Next time add JavaScript in your question and add the tag.